# JavaScript touchstart

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have question about 'touchstart' event. I have a button and I want to touch it. So I did 'touschstart' like this:

```
var button = document.getElementById('btn');   
button.addEventListener('touchstart', function(){something});
```

The problem is that 'touchstart' makes button clicked only one time. I want button to be 'pressed' all the time when user still touch it. How to do that?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do while the button is held down? If you're dragging something around you can use `touchmove`, if you want to do a continuous action you can create a setInterval on `touchstart` and then end it on `touchend`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to use two events. Both `tocuhstart`, and `touchend`.

```
var button = document.getElementById('btn');   
button.addEventListener('touchstart', function(){// make the button pressed});
button.addEventListener('touchend', function(){// make the button unpressed});
```

Comment: It's not working. It doesn't continue 'pressed' state. It just working like 'click' not like 'press mouse button and hold'

Comment: You set the object to the 'pressed' state in javascript on that event and remove that 'pressed' state with javascript on the up event. Its not going to be magic. What do you consider the 'pressed' state to be?

Comment: For example: you want to do console.log('hello') all the time when the button is pressed. So when user will hold the button 'down' for 10s it will do console.log all that time. That's exactly what I want to achieve.